# Keeping parent page active in the nav bar, when on a child page

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, parent

I am not showing the child pages in the menu, however I would like to highlight the parent page in the nav bar when in the three child pages.

My understanding is that the CSS that is already in the stylesheet should do the trick, however it isn't!  CSS below.

```
#nav >ul>li.hovered,
#nav >ul>li.current-menu-ancestor,
#nav >ul>li.current-menu-item {
  color: #e30613 !important;
}
#nav >ul>li.hovered >a,
#nav >ul>li.current-menu-ancestor >a,
#nav >ul>li.current-menu-item >a {
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
  color: #e30613 !important;
}
```

Any help would be gratefully received!